# Best method to import products, customers and Orders in Magento

Tags: magento, import, export

I am working on a new magento website whose design integration and functionality is almost complete. Now before I make the site live I need to import all my existing site data to my magento site. My old site has around 1000 products and is not a magento site. So I will get an excel sheet but its not in the format of magento excel sheet. So when i compare the current excel and create a new excel sheet for magento its very time consuming. So what is the best and speedy method to import products to a magento site. Anybody know please share the idea. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To import Products & Customers from another source. we have three option:

1. export data in CSV compatible with magento and import in magento.
2. you can use third party paid service for data migartion if it is supported by them. http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com. If you can afford this paid service then it is best time saving solution.
3. you can create a custom script to import data from csv that is not compatible or direct from external db.

one good product import script url as follows: http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/creating-magento-products-script

For importing Order in magento I will suggest you to use third party service.

Comment: Thanks will check these options.

Comment: Yah i have a chat with them but the cost is high. Let me check with script

Comment: Is there option for me to create an API for import products according to my purpose..